# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang/text/StrLookup Exception While Running Spring Boot Application

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

This is my POM.XML

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.vonage.gunify</groupId>
    <artifactId>gunify-ext-services-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2016.7.0-RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<artifactId>gunify-ext-services</artifactId>
<name>gunify-ext-services</name>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jadira.usertype</groupId>
        <artifactId>usertype.jodatime</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
        <version>0.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-hystrix-dashboard</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-jwt</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-zuul</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>pl.project13.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>git-commit-id-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

And my parent pom.xml

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.6.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <tomcat.version>8.0.3</tomcat.version>
</properties>

<modules>
    <module>gunify-ext-services</module>
    <module>dist</module>
</modules>

<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>VSLPluginRepo</id>
        <name>Vonage Service Layer Repository</name>
        <url>http://maven.dev.s.vonagenetworks.net:8080/nexus-webapp/content/repositories/VSL/</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <!-- <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy> -->
        </releases>
        <id>VSL</id>
        <name>Vonage Service Layer Repository</name>
        <url>http://maven.dev.s.vonagenetworks.net:8080/nexus-webapp/content/repositories/VSL/</url>
        <!-- <url>http://devserver-308.dev.s.vonagenetworks.net:7001/nexus-webapp/content/repositories/VSL/</url> -->
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
        <id>VONAGE-M2</id>
        <name>Vonage M2 Repository</name>
        <url>http://maven.dev.s.vonagenetworks.net:8080/nexus/content/repositories/Vonage-m2/</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>com.springsource.repository.bundles.release</id>
        <name>SpringSource Enterprise Bundle Repository - SpringSource Bundle Releases</name>
        <url>http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>com.springsource.repository.bundles.external</id>
        <name>SpringSource Enterprise Bundle Repository - External Bundle Releases</name>
        <url>http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>org.springframework.data</id>
        <name>Spring Data module for JPA repositories</name>
        <url>https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-jpa</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>JBossRepo</id>
        <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
        <id>vonage.maven1</id>
        <name>Vonage Maven1 Shadow Repository</name>
        <url>http://maven.dev.s.vonagenetworks.net:8080/nexus-webapp/content/shadows/Vonage-m1-m2/</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
        </snapshots>
        <id>VONAGE-SNAPSHOTS</id>
        <name>Vonage Service Layer Repository</name>
        <url>
            http://maven.dev.s.vonagenetworks.net:8080/nexus-webapp/content/repositories/VONAGE-SNAPSHOTS/
        </url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>VSL</id>
        <url>http://maven.dev.s.vonagenetworks.net:8080/nexus-webapp/content/repositories/VSL/</url>
    </repository>
</distributionManagement>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-releasetrain</artifactId>
            <version>Hopper-SR2</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>Brixton.SR4</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

And I am also Installed STS in Eclipse .

But i got error while running spring spoot application.

> >
>   2016-10-12 11:03:08,432 ERROR [org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication] Application startup failed
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'routingFilter' defined in file [C:\Users\apptivo\Music\Gunify\Gunify-git\gunify-ext-services\gunify-ext-services\target\classes\com\vonage\gunify\extservices\filter\RoutingFilter.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.vonage.gunify.extservices.filter.RoutingFilter]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang/text/StrLookup
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1105) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1050) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839) ~[spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538) ~[spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) ~[spring-boot-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar:1.3.6.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:760) ~[spring-boot-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar:1.3.6.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar:1.3.6.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:306) [spring-boot-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar:1.3.6.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1185) [spring-boot-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar:1.3.6.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1174) [spring-boot-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar:1.3.6.RELEASE]
>       at com.vonage.gunify.extservices.ExtensionServices.main(ExtensionServices.java:17) [classes/:?]
>   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.vonage.gunify.extservices.filter.RoutingFilter]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang/text/StrLookup
>       at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:163) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:89) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1098) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
>       ... 17 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang/text/StrLookup
>       at com.netflix.config.ConfigurationManager.createDefaultConfigInstance(ConfigurationManager.java:138) ~[archaius-core-0.7.4.jar:0.7.4]
>       at com.netflix.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfigInstance(ConfigurationManager.java:161) ~[archaius-core-0.7.4.jar:0.7.4]
>       at com.netflix.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfigInstance(ConfigurationManager.java:176) ~[archaius-core-0.7.4.jar:0.7.4]
>       at com.netflix.config.ConfigurationBasedDeploymentContext.(ConfigurationBasedDeploymentContext.java:108) ~[archaius-core-0.7.4.jar:0.7.4]
>       at com.netflix.config.ConfigurationManager.(ConfigurationManager.java:104) ~[archaius-core-0.7.4.jar:0.7.4]
>       at com.netflix.config.DynamicPropertyFactory.getInstance(DynamicPropertyFactory.java:277) ~[archaius-core-0.7.4.jar:0.7.4]
>       at com.netflix.zuul.ZuulFilter.(ZuulFilter.java:54) ~[zuul-core-1.1.0.jar:1.1.0]
>       at com.vonage.gunify.extservices.filter.AbstractZuulFilter.(AbstractZuulFilter.java:11) ~[classes/:?]
>       at com.vonage.gunify.extservices.filter.RoutingFilter.(RoutingFilter.java:6) ~[classes/:?]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_102]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_102]
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[?:1.8.0_102]
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[?:1.8.0_102]
>       at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:147) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:89) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1098) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
>       ... 17 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.lang.text.StrLookup
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[?:1.8.0_102]
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[?:1.8.0_102]
>       at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331) ~[?:1.8.0_102]
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[?:1.8.0_102]
>       at com.netflix.config.ConfigurationManager.createDefaultConfigInstance(ConfigurationManager.java:138) ~[archaius-core-0.7.4.jar:0.7.4]
>       at com.netflix.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfigInstance(ConfigurationManager.java:161) ~[archaius-core-0.7.4.jar:0.7.4]
>       at com.netflix.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfigInstance(ConfigurationManager.java:176) ~[archaius-core-0.7.4.jar:0.7.4]
>       at com.netflix.config.ConfigurationBasedDeploymentContext.(ConfigurationBasedDeploymentContext.java:108) ~[archaius-core-0.7.4.jar:0.7.4]
>       at com.netflix.config.ConfigurationManager.(ConfigurationManager.java:104) ~[archaius-core-0.7.4.jar:0.7.4]
>       at com.netflix.config.DynamicPropertyFactory.getInstance(DynamicPropertyFactory.java:277) ~[archaius-core-0.7.4.jar:0.7.4]
>       at com.netflix.zuul.ZuulFilter.(ZuulFilter.java:54) ~[zuul-core-1.1.0.jar:1.1.0]
>       at com.vonage.gunify.extservices.filter.AbstractZuulFilter.(AbstractZuulFilter.java:11) ~[classes/:?]
>       at com.vonage.gunify.extservices.filter.RoutingFilter.(RoutingFilter.java:6) ~[classes/:?]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_102]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_102]
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[?:1.8.0_102]
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[?:1.8.0_102]
>       at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:147) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:89) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1098) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
>       ... 17 more

Answer (score 4):

As the error message says : `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang/text/StrLookup`

That means, that apache commons-lang is missing in your dependencies:

So you have to add the following to your pom:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-lang/commons-lang -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
</dependency>
```

In addition is to say, you are using commons-lang3 but that has an other package Name `org/apache/commons/lang3`...

Comment: ,Thanks to sharing. I already tried to the above mentioned dependency in pom. But no luck to resolve this issue.

Comment: @mahalakshmi Your comment confused me! My solution do not help but you accept the answer?

Comment: your solution didnot help me.

Comment: @Why not? same exception ?

Comment: yes . after adding common-lang dependency. same exception occured @jens

Comment: that above error is solved.now new exception is arised java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang/exception/NestableRuntimeException

Comment: @mahalakshmi your are sure  that is excactly the same? Or is an other class not found?

Comment: yes jens getting same error in this class NestableRuntimeException

Comment: it is an other class that is missing. But it should be in the same jar

Comment: Before it was `StrLookup`

Comment: @mahalakshmi You have taken excatly my dependency?

Comment: yes. that strlookup solved. new class not found -  NestableRuntimeException  is arised now.. when search the solution for these exception,they said  same dependency "commons-lang" will add refer:NestableRuntimeException

Comment: Can i remove this dependency <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
   <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
   <version>3.4</version>
  </dependency>

Comment: @mahalakshmi if you read my answer i explain that you not should use `commons-lang3` because of a changed package Name. You should use `commons-lang` Version 2.6

Comment: When i removed commons-lang3 and used commons-lang (2.6) i got StrLookup - Class not found exception . When i used both , i got  class not found - NestableRuntimeException . What i do now . ? if you have chances ,ping me (skype ) mass.maha

Comment: @mahalakshmi please add the pom and the different error Messages to your question. normaly your Scenario can not happen. Sorry i have no skype